# Parent div doesn't auto set height to child div in photoslide

Tags: html, css, parent-child, slideshow, autosize

I need to make a website with a slideshow on the front page 100% width on the wrapper. The problem is that when I resize my window, the image resizes but the container height doesn't. The container doesn't change to the content inside and it overlaps with the other code because the container height is 0. Setting a min-height just fixes the problem for a certain resolution and I need it to be dynamic.

Is there anything else I can do?

```css
.slideshowcontainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.slideshowcontainer>div {
  position: absolute;
}

.slideshow {
  width: 100%;
}

.slideshow img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshowcontainer">
  <div class="slideshow fade">
    <img src="images/slideshow1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow fade">
    <img src="images/slideshow2.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try removing the absolute position on the div

Comment: It is needed to overlap the images in the slideshow

Comment: The code you posted doesn't reproduce the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/jr5wq1my/ Can you please modify?

Comment: This is the code I got in my website right now, the problem is still there https://jsfiddle.net/ednogh07/

Comment: The slideshow itself works but it's the height of the slideshow that doesn't set so it overlaps with content below